# Repeat last sentence

Tags: bots, repeat, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am using actions-on-google and Dialogflow to build a bot.

I was wondering how I can easily repeat the last sentence when asked by the user ("repeat please").

One way would be to have repeat followup intents in Dialogflow but this is quite heavy since :

- you need to add one after each intent and I have many
- in a multi-user environment you need to keep track of the last sentence for every user ...

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, the best way would be to take advantage of Dialogflow [Contexts](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts). As you send the message, you can also add that message to a context (for example, you can call it "last_message"). You can then have another Intent that takes as an input context the "last_message" context and, if triggered, uses the value saved in the context to repeat it.

@SysCoder has a [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/voice-repeater) that will help you do this for node.js.

*Clarification*

This assumes that you're generating the response through fulfillment. In cases like this, it should be fairly easy to save the message you're sending back in two places, rather than one. Libraries such as [voice-repeater](https://www.npmjs.com/package/voice-repeater) or [multivocal](http://multivocal.info/) handle much of this for you, but it isn't difficult to do yourself.

If you're handling all the replies through the Response section of the GUI, then this approach wouldn't work.

Comment: Just to clarify, this still means that in every intent you have to add that intent to Context "Last_message"? This means if I have 600 intents I will have to modify all of them? Is their a faster way to do this?

Comment: I've clarified the answer a bit. If that doesn't help, you may wish to open a new question with additional details of what you're trying to do and why this approach wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Take a universal variable and save all intent's response into it, and make an intent Repeat and its response is that universal variable.

```
 let prevSpeech = '';

 app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', (conv) => {
  const speech =`Welcome to My world`;
  conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech:speech,
    text: `Welcome to my world`,
 }));
 prevSpeech = speech;
});
app.intent('Repeat', (conv) => {
 conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
    speech:prevSpeech,
    text: prevSpeech
  }));
});
```

Comment: A global variable wouldn't work because this information needs to be tied to the user's session. Having it as a global means that if your function is called from multiple conversations (possibly with multiple users), the responses will be mixed. Similarly, if the function is on a server that is distributed or restarted (or using serverless functions, such as AWS Lambda or Google Cloud Functions) `prevSpeech` may be on a different server than the user previously hit.